# Is there a way to force kalarm to start minimized in the notification area?

Tags: autostart

I was having issues with gnome-schedule, so I've switched to kalarm. I have it running as a startup application in Ubuntu 10.10; however, it starts as a regular program and is open on the desktop upon boot.

Here's the command line that's in startup applications:

kalarm --tray -caption "%c" %i

Would love for this start minimized in the notifcation/tray area instead of having to manually do this...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alltray to send any application to the notification area. It's in the archives/repositories.